# Computing the FOLLOW() set of a grammar

Tags: compiler-construction

I'm reading [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) and I'm trying to compute the `FOLLOW()` sets of the following grammar:

```
S  →  iEtSS' | a
S' →  eS | ε
E  →  b
```

where `S, S', E` are *non-terminal* symbols, `S` is the *start* symbol, `i, t, a, e, b` are *terminal* symbols, and `ε` is the empty string.

**What I've done so far**

```
FOLLOW(S) = {$} ∪ FOLLOW(S')
FOLLOW(S') = FOLLOW(S)
FOLLOW(E) = FIRST(tSS') - {ε} = FIRST(t) - {ε} = {t} - {ε} = {t}
```

where `$` is the *input right endmaker*.

**Explanation**

`$ ∈ FOLLOW(S)`, since `S` is the start symbol. We also know that `S' →  eS`, so everything in `FOLLOW(S')` is in `FOLLOW(S)`. Therefore, `FOLLOW(S) = {$} ∪ FOLLOW(S')`.

We also know that `S  →  iEtSS'`, so everything in `FOLLOW(S)` is in `FOLLOW(S')`. Therefore, `FOLLOW(S') = FOLLOW(S)`.

The problem is that I can't compute `FOLLOW(S)`, since I don't know `FOLLOW(S')`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple algorithm, described in the text, is a *least fixed-point* computation. You basically cycle through the nonterminals, putting terminals into the follow sets, until you get through an entire cycle without changes.

Since nothing is ever removed from any follow set, and the number of terminals is finite, the algorithm must terminate. It usually only takes a few cycles.